# How to add Vertical line with same style as hr

Tags: html, css

I have this code I've done earlier .
I want to know how can I add a vertical line same as `hr`tag .
As you can see I want to add 2 vertical lines to seperate these 3 blocs.
Please open snippet in full page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> - Page acceuil</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />

    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

</head>
<!-- row -->
          <body>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 mb-3">
                <!-- text -->
              <h3 class="fw-semi-bold mb-3">Developper vos compétences</h3>
              <p class="fs-4">Avec notre platform on vous fournis des dernieres nouveautés pour assurer vos cours.</p>

            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 mb-3">
                <!-- text -->
              <h3 class="fw-semi-bold mb-3">Inspirer vos étudiants par vos cours</h3>
              <p class="fs-4">Aidez les gens à acquérir de nouvelles compétences, à faire progresser leur carrière et à explorer leurs passe-temps en partageant votre
                connaissances.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 mb-3">
                <!-- text -->
              <h3 class="fw-semi-bold mb-3">Rejoindre notre communité</h3>
              <p class="fs-4">Profitez de notre communauté active d'instructeurs pour vous aider dans votre processus de création de cours.
              </p>
            </div>
              
          </div>
          </body>
          </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this task using border property.
just give a class name to second column and apply that class.

```
.second-column{
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a `border-right: 2px solid #000` on `col-lg-4`. So the CSS should look like this:

```
<style>
.col-lg-4 {
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

If you don't like how the line looks, try changing its color, `#000` to any other hexadecimal, RGB value, or color name, change the nature of the line, `solid` to `dashed` or `dotted` or any other. You can also change the width of the line, `2px` to any value of any unit.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely way I would solve this would be to use CSS to add the line between the divs, this by giving the two first a class of eg. "vSeparator".

Then do something like this in the CSS file or add it to the top using the style tags.

```css
div.vSeparator {
    border-right: 1px solid black  
}
```